# How to schedule a task in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a django app which will take backup from mysql depends on the given parameter.
I have a view which will get the user parameters from a form.The following are the parameters:

1.mysql username

2.mysql password

3.database name

4.backup path

Now I'll take the parameters and give it as arguments to a function I wrote which will take take the mysql backup.Now I need to work this as a cronjobs kind of thing with celery or some other similar to that.
this is my view:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = myform(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
             mysqlusername = form.cleaned_data['mysqlusername']
             mysqlpassword = form.cleaned_data['mysqlpassword']
             database_name = form.cleaned_data['database_name']
             backuppath    = form.cleaend_data['backuppath']

             backupfunction(mysqlusername, mysqlpassword, database_name, backkuppath)
     else: 
            form = myform()

 def backupfunction(mysqlusername, mysqlpassword, database_name, backuppath):
           (code to take backup)
```

Comment: unless you store the username/password somewhere, the cronjob would not get the required parameters. Are you storing the credentials somewhere ??

Comment: currently the above codes works fine,but am not using cronjobs am using os.system() to take the backup

Answer (score 0):

You can use the django celery. Which provide scheduler as well as asynchronous task. For details
  https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/06/23/scheduling-tasks-celery/

You have to create a task.py file in your app. And Write your function in that file

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task()
def testschduler():
    print "scdule task"
```

After this just go the admin panel create a crowntab job. In database. That will automatically read by celryd.

Comment: Although suggestion is good you should add a minimal code example how to setup simple task - other way your answer can be flagged as "link only answer"

Comment: okay thing is I need to give the crontab input from the user mean from a form

Comment: django admin provide form to create crontab. You can overide that or can use that.

Comment: enough with the celery.